# Change color of disabled toolbar button

Tags: swift, toolbar

I need to change the color of a disabled toolbar button. I have tried multiple methods.

1.

```
button.isEnabled = false
button.tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

2.

```
button.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue], for: .disabled)
```

Neither of them seems to work. Is there a way to change the color of a disabled toolbar item?

note: this item was created in the storyboard and I am loading it from an outlet
edit: I should have explained this earlier but the buttons have pictures and the tint color seems to be the only thing that works for changing the color of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Xcode bug. Use UIButton instead. You can just drag and drop it into the tabbar in storyboard.

And then just use title color:

```
 button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .disabled)
```

Comment: The problem is that my button is displayed as an image. When using this strategy changing the color does not actually change the color of the image.

Comment: @joshLor you should use image as templae `UIImage(named:"myImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)` (also you can change render mode in image assets properties). Then set butoon tint color for disabled state and image will change color automatically.

Comment: Thanks so much it worked but, is it possible for me to change the color back to gray when the button is enabled.

Comment: @joshLor yes,
`button.setTintColor(.grey, for: .normal)`

Comment: Set tint color or set title color

Comment: @joshLor if you aren't setup title color, tint color for button will change image and text (title) color. If you setupped unique title color, tint color will change only image color. Anyway tint color changes image color.

Comment: Thanks, My last problem is that the button still looks disabled as the alpha is all screwed up, is this fixable as well. I already tried changing the alpha.

Comment: @joshLor if you want disable button without `cosmetic` changes, you can use `userInteractionEnabled`.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

I didn't want my image to be lighter so what worked for me was to force to use that same image for disabled status, like this:

```
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "MyBackgroundColor"), for: .disabled)
```